# Python Struct and reading values in Java

Tags: java, python, binary

I want to export a binary format and then I read the binary in Java, But i am not able to get correct values, for example

```
f.write(struct.pack('<f', 21.988))
```

in Java I have this value: `8.962863E27`

I try to send a binary and match the output to ubjson library written in java, at first I use Big-endian mark but does not work, and when I use Little-endian it works like that.

Thanks for any guides.

**Edit: some part of library**

```
public JsonValue parse(final DataInputStream din) throws IOException {
        return parse(din, din.readByte());
    }

    protected JsonValue parse(final DataInputStream din, final byte type) throws IOException {
        if (type == '[')
            return parseArray(din);
        else if (type == '{')
            return parseObject(din);
        else if (type == 'Z')
            return new JsonValue(JsonValue.ValueType.nullValue);
        else if (type == 'T')
            return new JsonValue(true);
        else if (type == 'F') 
                .....
```

Comment: Have you looked at the file encoding to ensure that it's reading both files in the exact same format?

Comment: Mike I edited Post with part of library, it uses default Java Streams and read bytes.

Comment: and you're opening the file in python as 'wb' correct?  Which is binary mode in python (only required on windows - but should be left in for cross platform support).

Comment: thanks, but I export to Java, as @martin wrote it was problem of Big/little-endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java application is using the opposite endianess; you are writing little-endian, but Java interpreted the value as big endian:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>f', struct.pack('<f', 21.988))
(8.962863280123082e+27,)
```

Write big-endian and Java will read the values correctly:

```
struct.pack('>f', 21.988)
```

If that doesn't work there are *other* reasons that your output is not interpreted correctly. The [UBJSON specification](http://ubjson.org/#endian) is quite clear about endianess, it should all be encoded big-endian.

Comment: @daniel: Then study the source code I linked you to some more. It *certainly* uses big-endian packing and unpacking.

Comment: @martin I studied before, in 3 days researching and tests.

Comment: I didn't say you had not. But you'll need to compare your output with that of that library. Switching to little-endianess is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @martin, you answer was currect, but I do not know other part is still in little-endian but float number in big-endian, and it works, f.write(struct.pack('<s', b"vert"))
f.write(struct.pack('<c', b"d"))
f.write(struct.pack('>f', 21.988))

Comment: Characters are just *one* byte long, so there is no difference between endianess. `struct.pack('<s', b"vert") == struct.pack('>s', b"vert")` is `True`.

Comment: @daniel: I have no idea what that error might be. Is it a Python error? Then I can perhaps help. Java errors not so much. But the *specification* is very clear as to what endianess needs to be used, and the behaviour you talk about in your question is caused *exactly* by using little endianess where you need to use big endianess.

Comment: Thanks for time & guide @martin, i will continue on testing and research see can I find useful infos.